# Solr returned an error #400 (Bad Request) for url

Tags: solr

I am using *Solr 6.5.0*, and I came across a scenario where I have to index a data field which may of multiple languages in the document.

I am trying to use a separate field for each language and I have to index the data of specific language to the corresponding field defined for that language.

I have added below config and schema changes:

**Solr config:**

```
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
       <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="update.chain">langid</str>
       </lst>    
    </requestHandler>
    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="langid">
         <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.TikaLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
           <str name="langid.fl">title</str>
           <str name="langid.langField">lang</str>
           <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
         </processor>
         <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
         <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
       </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

**schema:**

```
<field name="code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="content_english" type="text_english" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="content_french" type="text_french" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="content_spanish" type="text_spanish" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**Input xml:**

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="code">one</field>
  <field name="title">Adventures</field>
  <field name="content_english">Especially the fuzzy search is very welcome; Solr really is a beautiful engine and it’s incredibly fast: millions of documents are no problem. Of course, if your servers capacities are configured correctly.</field>    
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="code">two</field>
  <field name="title">Aventures</field>
  <field name="content_french">Surtout la recherche floue est très bienvenue; Solr est vraiment un beau moteur et c'est incroyablement rapide: des millions de documents ne posent aucun problème. Bien sûr, si les capacités de vos serveurs sont configurées correctement.</field>    
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="code">three</field>
  <field name="title">Aventuras</field>
  <field name="content_spanish">Especialmente la búsqueda difusa es muy bienvenida; Solr realmente es un motor hermoso y es increíblemente rápido: millones de documentos no son ningún problema. Por supuesto, si las capacidades de los servidores están configuradas correctamente.</field>    
</doc>
</add>
```

whenever I update the core, I'am getting the below error:

```
C:\solr-6.5.0\example\exampledocs>java
-Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/autodetect/update?update.chain=langid -jar post.jar multilanguage.xml SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
```

> Posting files to [base] url
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/autodetect/update?update.chain=langid using
>   content-type application/xml... POSTing file multilanguage.xml to
>   [base] SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #400 (Bad
>   Request) for url:
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/autodetect/update?update.chain=langid
>   SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response:   4006org.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionorg.apache.solr.common.SolrExceptionDocument is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id400  SimplePostTool: WARNING:
>   IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/autodetect/update?update.chain=langid 1
>   files indexed. COMMITting Solr index changes to
>   http://localhost:8983/solr/autodetect/update?update.chain=langid...
>   Time spent: 0:00:00.179

Answer (score 1):

Error : ID field is missing from your documents.

`id` which is used to identify each document uniquely is specified in schema file like below.

```
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Every document must and should have field which specified as uniquekey.

Include Id field for all your docs and check. 
ex:

```
<doc>
  <field name="id">001</field>
  <field name="code">one</field>
  <field name="title">Adventures</field>
  <field name="content_english">Especially the fuzzy search is very welcome; Solr really is a beautiful engine and it’s incredibly fast: millions of documents are no problem. Of course, if your servers capacities are configured correctly.</field>    
</doc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well have you looked at the error? Your documents don't have a value for the mandatory field called 'id'. You either have to give each one an id:

```
<add>
<doc>
  <field name="code">one</field>
  <field name="id">1</field>
  <field name="title">Adventures</field>
  <field name="content_english">Especially the fuzzy search is very welcome; Solr really is a beautiful engine and it’s incredibly fast: millions of documents are no problem. Of course, if your servers capacities are configured correctly.</field>    
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="code">two</field>
  <field name="id">2</field>
  <field name="title">Aventures</field>
  <field name="content_french">Surtout la recherche floue est très bienvenue; Solr est vraiment un beau moteur et c'est incroyablement rapide: des millions de documents ne posent aucun problème. Bien sûr, si les capacités de vos serveurs sont configurées correctement.</field>    
</doc>
<doc>
  <field name="code">three</field>
  <field name="id">3</field>
  <field name="title">Aventuras</field>
  <field name="content_spanish">Especialmente la búsqueda difusa es muy bienvenida; Solr realmente es un motor hermoso y es increíblemente rápido: millones de documentos no son ningún problema. Por supuesto, si las capacidades de los servidores están configuradas correctamente.</field>    
</doc>
</add>
```

Or you can configure Solr to automatically assign a value if one isn't present.